# Getting Older timestamp from query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, postgresql-9.4

Below is my method to fetch current database time using select query.

```
public Date getDBDateTime() { 
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   
    return (Date) session.createSQLQuery("select now() as date").uniqueResult();    
}
```

this method returns the current timestamp from database but once in a while this method returns older timestamp from db. (sometimes 30s to 1 min old)

here is my service layer method in spring which calls above dao method.

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(){
   Date now  = dao.getDBDateTime();
   //service specific logic
}
```

need to select db time for some event timing calculation and to have db and app servers decoupled from same time-zone.

can anyone point me where am i going wrong and suggestions to fix it ?

Thanks in anticipation !

Comment: Is you db and application on different servers / timezone ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra currently they are on different servers but same timezone.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your issue, I would suggest to get the date in String format and convert that string to **LocalDateTime** using Java.

Comment: Does the `getDBDateTime()` returns `java.util.Date`? Or some other `Date`?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala No, it's not java.util.Date but it returns java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra but how would that solve the problem ? what if date in string format too is an old value.  I would like to know where this problem originating from due to postgres or hibernate.

Comment: Do you have any scenarios in which this issue can be reproducible ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I reproduced it by making multiple rest api calls on this service method via controller.

Comment: What is your server timezone ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the sample app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`now()` does not return the wall time, but the current timestamp at the beginning of the transaction. Calling `now()` repeatedly inside one transaction will always return the same value. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for more.

So I suspect that you have a long running open transaction if `now()` returns an old time. That is an application bug, because long running transactions will keep `VACUUM` from doing its work and also locks objects for a long time.

To get the current wall time, use the function `clock_timestamp()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my application, the service layer code is called by a controller which is a rest api and returns in ms. so how can there be a long running transaction ? I mean if i fire an api at 2.00 pm and it takes 1 second to return response then also old timestamp of 30s-1m is not justified with this logic. am i missing something ?

Comment: I don't know your setup, but you can use `SELECT xact_start FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();` to find out when your current transaction has been started.

Comment: Thanks using clock_timestamp() actually fixed the issue but i am still not able to figure out the reason behind long running running transactions. I use to think from session which i receive from sessionfactory provides a new transaction everytime for each rest call. can you suggest me some further reference/reading to dig out the issue please ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Hibernate, but I assume it is either a bug there or in the way you use it. Sorry if I cannot help you further. It might be useful to set `log_statement = 'all'` in PostgreSQL and examine what Hibernate really does. Maybe that gives you a clue.